# Vertical alignment of image in multirow column in tabularx at the top of the cell?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow

I want to place an image with `includegraphics` in a `multirow` table cell in a `tabularx`,
and it shall be vertically aligned with the top of the cell.

Example with a `rule` instead of the image:

```
    \documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[TS1, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}p{3cm} X r}  \hline
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{{\huge{}My Beautiful Text}} & 
\multirow{4}{*}{\rule{4cm}{6.5cm}%\includegraphics[height=6.5cm]{../../../2012_Bewerbungsfotos/2012-01_MB_Bewerbungsfoto_col.jpg}
}\\[24pt]
a & b\\[6pt]
a & b\\[6pt]
a & b\\[6pt]
a & b\\[6pt]
a & b
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Screenshot of PDF:
[image]

How can I place the image directly at the `\hline` (identical with the top of the line where multirow is defined)?

**EDIT** to explain my "real" purpose:

- In the real document, there is no `hline` at the top of the `tabularx` (I only added the `hline` to better view the top of the cells),
  but I'd like the inserted image to be aligned with the top of the text, as it does not look good IMHO if the image which spans over the whole height of the table starts below the text.
  (the original document contains personal data, so I tried to construct an artificial minimal example.)
- the first line of the table is the only one with `huge` font size (heading), all the others are normalsize.
  *

Comment: What's the purpose of this?

Comment: I've edited the question to explain what the "real" purpose is.

Comment: See the edited answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\huge` command raises the row height, but `\multirow` doesn't respect it. It would work if you would place `\huge` before the tabular environment. This would affect the cells, but you could use `>{\normalsize}` for the column specifiers. Yet the rows would be higher.

```
\begingroup
\huge
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\normalsize}p{3cm}>{\normalsize}X>{\normalsize}r@{}}\hline
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{{\huge{}My Beautiful Text}} & 
\multirow{4}{*}{\rule{4cm}{6.5cm}%\includegraphics[height=6.5cm]{../..
...
\end{tabularx}

\endgroup
```

[image: multirow adjusted]

Alternatively, use the optional `fixup` height argument for raising the image:

```
\multirow{nrows}[bigstruts]{width}[fixup]{text}
```

With a `fixup` height you could compensate that you actually use different row heights.

Comment: How can you avoid the increment of row height while maintaining the image height you desire. As i can see in your example above, there is a shift of about 1cm up of "My Beautiful Text" from the text a & b.

Comment: That's why I recommend simply using a fixup value. 5pt works fine in the example.

Comment: @Stefan I finally chose the manual method with the `fixup` value, as there seems to be no "automatic" solution which does not involve typing by hand the height of the `\huge` text, if I understand your and egreg's solution

Answer (score 2):

A different approach is to put the image *outside* the tabular. We lower the image by its height minus the height of the strut in `\huge` size. The `tabularx` is "top aligned", so the image will be lined up with the first row; the depth of the box is made a bit longer (1ex) to help with the spacing underneath.

```
\newcommand{\foto}{%
  {\huge
   \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox\relax}[0pt][\dimexpr\height-\ht\strutbox+1ex\relax]%
    {%
     \rule{4cm}{6.5cm}% put the image here
    }}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\textwidth-6.5cm\relax}[t]{@{}p{3cm} X}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\huge\strut My Beautiful Text} \\[24pt]
a & b\\[6pt]
a & b\\[6pt]
a & b\\[6pt]
a & b\\[6pt]
a & b
\end{tabularx}\foto
```

[image]